# Entity Framework Code First and populating join tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4, sql-server-express

I been practicing with EF Code First, SQL Express, and ASP.Net MVC3.

When I run the website first the correct tables are generated by the `FooInitializer` and `Student` and `Image` are populated but for some reason the join table (`StudentImages`) is not being populated.

What could be the issue?

Tables: `Student`, `Image`, and `StudentImages`

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Image> Images  { get; set; }
}

public class Image
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Filename { get; set; }
    public string Extension { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Student> Students { get; set; }
}

public class FooInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<DBContext>
{

    protected override void Seed(DBContext context)
    {
    var students = new List<Student> {
        new Student { Id = 1, Name = "John" },
        new Student { Id = 2, Name = "Jane" }
    };

    students.ForEach(s => context.Students.Add(s));
    context.SaveChanges();


    var images = new List<Image> {
    new Image { Id = 1, Filename = "IMG_4596.JPG", Extension = ".jpg" },
        new Image { Id = 2, Filename = "IMG_4600.JPG", Extension = ".jpg" }
    };

    images.ForEach(i => context.Images.Add(i));

    students[0].Images.Add(images[0]);
    context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

Comment: trying these out now - thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell your Image class does not have a reference to the StudentID. Try adding:

```
public int StudentID { get; set; }
```

to the Image class maybe?

Also having an ICollection would mean that one image could have multiple students - is this correct? Maybe it should be a public virtual Student Student {...}

EDIT: Also I found this, with a many to many relationship (if thats what you need):

In your OnModelCreating() Method:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
    .HasMany(c => c.Images).WithMany(i => i.Students)
    .Map(t => t.MapLeftKey("StudentId")
        .MapRightKey("ImageID")
        .ToTable("StudentImages"));
```

taken from [this](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) link that states:

> A many-to-many relationship between the Instructor and Course
>   entities. The code specifies the table and column names for the join
>   table. Code First can configure the many-to-many relationship for you
>   without this code, but if you don't call it, you will get default
>   names such as InstructorInstructorID for the InstructorID column.

EDIT: Here is the code I used the other night, with my implementation of the code first MVC site:

```
var users = new List<User> 
            {
                new User { UserID = new Guid(), Email = "me@me.com", LastOnline = DateTime.Now, Password = "pword", RegistrationDate = DateTime.Now, SecurityAnswer = "me", SecurityQuestion = "who?", Roles = new List<Role>() },
            };

            users.ForEach(s => context.Users.Add(s));
            context.SaveChanges();

            var roles = new List<Role>
            {
                new Role { RoleID = "Admin", Description = "Administration Users", Users = new List<User>() }

            };
            roles.ForEach(r => context.Roles.Add(r));


            users[0].Roles.Add(roles[0]);
            context.SaveChanges();



            var userLicense = new List<UserLicense>
            {
                new UserLicense { AddDateTime = DateTime.Now, LicenseType = "Farmer", Manufacturer = "Motorola", Model = "Droid", PhoneIdentifier = "c0e4223a910f", UserID = users[0].UserID, User = new User() }

            };
            userLicense[0].User = users[0];
            userLicense.ForEach(u => context.UserLicenses.Add(u));
            context.SaveChanges();

            userLicense[0].User = users[0];
            context.SaveChanges();
```

Notice in each instantiated item, I am also instantiating a new referenced item within the parent object.

EDIT:

Ok try this:

```
var students = new List<Student> {
    new Student { Id = 1, Name = "John", Images = new List<Image>() },
    new Student { Id = 2, Name = "Jane", Images = new List<Image>() }
};

students.ForEach(s => context.Students.Add(s));
context.SaveChanges();


var images = new List<Image> {
    new Image { Id = 1, Filename = "IMG_4596.JPG", Extension = ".jpg", Students = new List<Student>()  },
    new Image { Id = 2, Filename = "IMG_4600.JPG", Extension = ".jpg", Students = new List<Student>() }
};

images.ForEach(i => context.Images.Add(i));

students[0].Images.Add(images[0]);
students[1].Images.Add(images[1]);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: I tried the replacing the ICollection to Student Student but the join table is not being created unfortunately.

Comment: using the code as per in the question - added the modelBuilder code above and still no data in the join table

Comment: tried changing my code to match yours and I am receiving an exception Object reference not set to an instance of an object. at the equivalent line to your users[0].Roles.Add(roles[0]);

Comment: Also let me ask you, what is the relationship between image/student? 1 student to many images? I will look further into this this evening.

Comment: Cheers Jack. They are meant to be many to many and thats why I need the StudentImages table which is been created correctly but not being populated. I am using a public virtual ICollection<> referencing each other in order to create the many to many.

Comment: Thanks Jack - it was the Images = new List<Image>() missing from my initialization of the Students list. Well done!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding this before saving changes for each student:

```
foreach (Image i in s1.Images)
    context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(i, System.Data.EntityState.Added);
```

Also try with System.Data.EntityState.Modified.

Hope this works...

Comment: didn't seem to have any affect